# SDL not rendering truetype font

Tags: c++, fonts, truetype, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

I'm not entirely sure this is the best place for this, but I can't think of anywhere better

I've "made" a low resolution [font](http://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1031299). (bonus points if you know where it's actually from)

The font works fine in gedit: [image: gedit]

However, when trying to render the font with SDL_ttf, it mostly works, except for some multibyte unicode characters (notably '[æ](http://graphemica.com/%C3%A6)' and '[℃](http://graphemica.com/%E2%84%83)') while other non-ASCII characters work fine. But(!), all of these characters work fine with other fonts (I've been using DejaVu Sans)

[image: My Font] [image: Dejavu Sans]

The fact that other fonts work fine suggest that the code is not to blame, but just in case:

```
SDL_Surface *surf = TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid(this->font, (const char *)text, col);
if (surf == nullptr) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Rendering text failed (%s)\n", TTF_GetError());
    return;
}

if (surf->format->BitsPerPixel != 8 || surf->format->BytesPerPixel != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Rendering text failed (Wrong surface format)\n");
    return;
}
```

(text is const uint8*) None of these errors are triggered, obviously

I've noticed that these 2 characters in particular are wider than the rest, could this be to blame?

Per comment below, the font seems to work fine with the SDL_TTF "latin-1" demo:

[image: working in demo]

Comment: "Some multibyte Unicode characters" is the same as "other non-ASCII characters"? That is, those other characters are also "multibyte Unicode characters"? (The common name, by the way, is "UTF8".) Can you compile, run, and test your font with the demos on https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf?

Comment: (OT) The font reminds me heavily of the good old 8-bit days. Your capitals immediately reminded me of Mastertronic's *Spellbound*.

Comment: font seems to work fine in the demos: http://i.imgur.com/yMHuHqM.png (the 'latin-1' program) I guess we can see where the mystery 'unknown' chracter is coming from, a product of using this fontstruct site, i guess (despite me defining my own "undefined" character). So, i've got no idea what's going on...

Comment: Unfortunately, one needs to Sign In to download your font, so I cannot test it with my OTF-checking software (to rule out an error inside the font itself). Since you are using UTF8-encoding, can you try that demo as well?

Comment: oh, never realised that - have a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/82idr33bnlhc8ot/RCT1.zip

Comment: and which demo where? i can't see any others...

Comment: *not-so-subtle-poke* any further ideas?

Comment: The font works fine for me, with the showfont demo included with SDL-ttf. Perhaps it's a version issue? I have SDL-ttf 2.0.11 and freetype 2.5.2.

Comment: i have SDL_ttf 2.0.12 (iirc, it's just a rebuild for SDL2) and freetype 2.5.3

Comment: Can you include a minimal compilable example that reproduces the issue?  It doesn't seem to be your font or the code you posted.

Comment: I... i have no idea what was wrong. It works in minimal version, and now of course it works in the main version too. http://i.imgur.com/Hz5gNxf.png Typical. Regardless, thanks for attempting to help guys :)

Comment: (OT) Oh, and the answer you were looking for was Roller Coaster Tycoon :) http://freerct.org </shamelessplug>

Comment: So it works with the *exact same code* as in your question? If not, then you might put it in an answer yourself.

Comment: Yeah, weird. Maybe I was using the wrong font or something.... ;_;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I.. I don't know what was wrong. I just tried it again, and it worked fine.

[image]

I was so sure I'd checked that I was using the correct font.. Or maybe I changed something when I generated it

Thanks for the help regardless :)